# How to send array and object with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am a beginner with curl. I want to make a request where I post different data.

I have a code

```
$curl = curl_init();


$fields = (object) array(
     'contactFilter' => (object) array(
          'clicked_message.messageid' => '5',
          'messages_sent.messageid' => '5'
      ),
     'exportAttributes' => 'email',
   );

$fields = json_encode($fields);

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/export",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'api-key: my-key-12345',
  ),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields_string
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Documentation says that I need;

```
contactFilter object (X= campaign id): {"clicked_message.messageid": X,"messages_sent.messageid": X}
```

and

```
exportAttributes` array of strings For example, `['fname', 'lname, 'email'].
```

how should my request should look like?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to post the fields, for example

```
$fields = array(
        'username' => "annonymous",
        'api_key' =>  "1234"
    ); 
 $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

Now use variable fields_string to send array data

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
```

Your curl request will be look like

```
curl_setopt_array($curl,
  array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/export",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields_string
  )
);
```

Updated Code-

```
$curl = curl_init();


$fields = (object) array(
 'contactFilter' => (object) array(
      'clicked_message.messageid' => '5',
      'messages_sent.messageid' => '5'
  ),
 'exportAttributes' => 'email',
);

$fields = json_encode($fields);

//$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/export",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'api-key: my-key-12345',
  ),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;

print_r($response);
```

Comment: thank you, can you tell my how should look like json object with all params that I needed? I tried this
$fields = array(
     'contactFilter' => (object) array(
          'clicked_message.messageid' => '5',
          'messages_sent.messageid' => '5'
      ),
     'exportAttributes' => 'email'
   );

Comment: Nothing happens, I updated my question wth full code that i wrote now. I cant understand how to pass key and object..

Comment: your code is correct just comment line //$fields = json_encode($fields);

Comment: i get an error {"error":{"status":400,"message":"Input must be a valid JSON object","code":"bad_request"}}

Comment: {"code":"invalid_parameter","message":"Invalid export attributes format"}

Comment: curl is working, you have to make sure the passing array element are correct

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand this part of the documentation?
contactFilter
object
Set the filter for the contacts to be exported. For example, {'blacklisted':true} 
To get clickers list for some particular campaign X (X= campaign id)

{"clicked_message.messageid": X,"messages_sent.messageid": X}